# How do I add filters in Twenty-Twenty-Three without a functions.php?

Tags: block-editor

The theme twenty-twenty-three does not have its functions.php. How to I add a filter?

e.g.

```
add_filter( 'simpletoc_wrapper_enabled', '__return_true' );
```

Is there a another way? Just adding a functions.php with <?php and the above code did not work. I could think of a child theme but that would be to much work just for that.

Comment: In a one-file plugin instead? I'm surprised the functions.php didn't work though.

Comment: or a child theme, there's nothing special about `functions.php` it's just a place to put code, lots of other places exist. Even if 2023 had a `functions.php` you should never modify a themes functions file as all your changes are destroyed on update, use a child theme ( there are generators )

Comment: The plugin worked. But functions.php in the 2023 folder did not. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tested this just now, created functions.php in twenty-twenty-three and it does work.
I created two full site editing themes so far, and both have functions.php, so it definitely works.
My previous remark about supplying true argument to filter was incorrect, thanks to @Rup for pointing that out. `add_filter` parameter is always callable and `__return_true` is callable which points to function returning true.

So I would conclude, if it does not work it is likely plugin bug, or another bug in your code.

Also, you should create and use child theme, because with next theme update (which do happen!) your function.php will likely be deleted.

Comment: @Rup yes, my mistake